# Adelic formulations of complex multiplication and modular curves

Tags: adeles, complex-multiplication, modular-forms, shimura-varieties, nt.number-theory

In modular curves and modular forms, there is an adelic formulation, in which smaller open subgroups of some adelic group relate to higher level structure. As we know, higher level structure corresponds to higher torsion points (when we say "higher" we mean, e.g., $E[n]$ is "higher" than $E[m]$ if $m \mid n$). In complex multiplication, higher torsion points correspond to higher ray class fields, which correspond to smaller open subgroups of the ideles of the field of complex multiplication in question! (*Since someone asked, I sketch this in more detail below)

Thus I would like to ask whether there is a formulation that combines the adelic formulation of complex multiplication with the adelic formulation of modular curves.

To simplify and thus explain the principles**, it would be best to work with elliptic curves with complex multiplication. Let $F$ be a quadratic imaginary field.

Then I have the following guess for an idea: We have an injection from the ideles of $F$ into the rational adelic points of $\mathrm{GL}_2$, and after quotienting by the rational (i.e. non-adelic) points, we still have a nice inclusion? I would guess that the resulting points at those corresponding to CM elliptic curves and their level structures, but I don't entirely understand how to prove this.

Furthermore, assuming this is true, what does this say about the Galois action? Does this allow us to construct the Galois action (i.e. rational structure) on modular curves?

(Also, to be even more precise, we should let the ideles of $F$ be represented by the adelic points of the Weil restriction of $G_m$ from $F$ to $\mathbb{Q}$).

*In the adelic formulation of modular curves, we view modular curves as quotients of the adelic points of $GL_2$. We get different modular curves, e.g. $\Gamma(N)$ instead of $\Gamma(M)$ (for $M,N$ some positive integers) by considering different open subgroups of the adeles. As is well-known, $\Gamma(N)$ parametrizes elliptic curves with "level N" structure, meaning pairs consisting of elliptic curves and $N$-torsion points. In complex multiplication, the $N$-torsion points correspond to the ray class field of level $N$, and this is, in particular, done through an adelic formulation of the main theorem of complex multiplication.

**Though I assume everything will extend to higher-dimensional Shimura varieties in an analogous way.

Comment: I would really appreciate, if you sketch  out the correspondances indicated in the first paragraph, or at least give a reference for this.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but Silverman's book Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves gives an adelic formulation of the main results on complex multiplication for elliptic curves.

Comment: @Mrc Plm: I added a bit more at the bottom under **

@David Speyer: I tried to edit the question to explain a bit more. I understand the adelic formulation of the main theorem (I've read Silverman). I'm wondering whether there is a direct connection between the adelic formulation of the main theorem of complex multiplication and the adelic formulation of modular curves.

Comment: Ah, okay, I did actually know that;) I guess you embed $F^\times$ into $A_F^\times$, and want to interpret $A_F^\times$ as the stabilizer of the elliptic elements in $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ corresponding to $F$, and see whether this useful?

Comment: I can't quite tell if this is helpful or not, but: Let $F$ be an imaginary quadratic field, $G=GL_2$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $H=GL_1$ over $F$ (restricted to be over $\mathbb Q$). Via an isomorphism $F\simeq \mathbb Q^2$, we can consider $H$ as a subgroup of $G$. The modular curve is something like $Z_{\mathbb A} G_\mathbb Q\backslash G_\mathbb A/K$, where $K$ is a compact open subgroup of $G_\mathbb A$ and $Z$ is the center of $G$. The image of $H_\mathbb A$ in the modular curve is then $Z_\mathbb A H_F\backslash H_\mathbb A/K\cap H_\mathbb A$. (continued)

Comment: (continued) When $K$ is the full maximal compact subgroup, this is just the class group of $F$. Generally, it will be a ray class group of $F$.

Comment: @Mrc Plm: Yes. OR If that is not true, at least something similar.

Comment: @BR: I think you're probably right, and since the ray class group corresponds to elliptic curves with complex multiplication by F with level structure (by complex multiplication), I'm guessing that the image is the subset of the points of the given modular curves whose points correspond specifically to those CM elliptic curves with those particular level structure.

The main question I then have is what this tells us about the Galois action on modular curves.

Comment: David, unfortunately, I'm no expert in this area. What little I understand comes from reading some of Milne's expository work, like http://jmilne.org/math/articles/2003a.pdf and, more generally, http://jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf

Comment: BR has it basically right. The adelic formulation gives you a map (let's call it $\eta$) from the pro-finite set $H(\mathbb{Q})∖H(\mathbb{A}_f)$ to the inverse limit of the modular curves over varying levels. The main theorem of complex multiplication can be interpreted as saying that, if you equip the pro-finite set with the $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K)$-action induced from the global reciprocity map for $K$, then $\eta$ is compatible with Galois actions and is therefore defined over $K$.

Comment: For $K$ read $F$ everywhere.

Comment: Shou-Wu Zhang discussed this in his graduate course on Heegner points this past semester.  (The class followed http://www.math.columbia.edu/~szhang/papers/elc.pdf up through the end of chapter 4, and then went on to talk about adelic modular curves instead of the full generality of Shimura curves).  You should talk to him when you're back in Princeton.

Comment: Dear Davidac, Just to add to Keerthi's answer, you are asking for an adelic formulation of the Shimura reciprocity law, in the context of CM elliptic curves.  This can be found in texts on Shimura varieties (in more generality), e.g. in Deligne's Bourbaki seminars, or in Langlands's article *Ein Maerchen* (highly recommended for this and many other reasons).  Regards, Matthew 

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that my answer is basically a specialization of a statement that can be found in Deligne's Bourbaki talk 'Travaux de Shimura'. The precise reference there would be Theorem 4.9 and the discussion following it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an expansion of my comment above: You can view the modular curve of level $K$ over $\mathbb{C}$ as the double coset space
$$GL_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash\mathbb{H}^{\pm}\times GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)/K.$$
Here, $\mathbb{H}^{\pm}$ is the union of the half planes. This set is in bijection with isogeny classes of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ with $K$-level structure, and the bijection is obtained as follows: A point $\tau\in\mathbb{H}^{\pm}$ gives us an isomorphism of vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^2\xrightarrow{\simeq}\mathbb{C}$, which in turn equips $\mathbb{Q}^2$ with a Hodge structure of weights $(0,-1),(-1,0)$. This allows us to interpret it as the $\mathbb{Q}$-homology of an elliptic curve $E_{\tau}$ (This is just a fancier way of saying that $E_{\tau}=\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\tau)$). So, given a point $[(\tau,g)]$ in the double coset space, we attach to it the elliptic curve (up to isogeny) $E_{\tau}$, with the $K$-level structure given by the $K$-orbit of the isomorphism
$$\mathbb{A}_f^2\xrightarrow{g}\mathbb{A}_f^2= H_1(E_{\tau},\mathbb{A}_f).$$

Let $\alpha$ be some generator of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$: it allows us to identify $F$ with $\mathbb{Q}^2$. Choose an embedding $F$ in $\mathbb{C}$, so that $\alpha$ can be viewed as an element of $\mathbb{H}$. Let $H$ be the rank $2$ torus over $\mathbb{Q}$ attached to $F$: we can view it as the sub-group of $GL_2$ that commutes with the action of $F$. We then get a map 
$$\eta:H(\mathbb{Q})\backslash H(\mathbb{A}_f)\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash\mathbb{H}^{\pm}\times GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)/K$$
$$\;\;\;\;[h]\mapsto [(\alpha,h)].$$
The image of this map consists exactly of those elliptic curves admitting CM by $F$, whose level structures admit an $F$-equivariant representative. (One subtlety is that, if $E$ is an elliptic curve in the image, then you can also look at the curve $\overline{E}$, where you twist the action of $F$ by complex conjugation. This won't show up in the image of $\eta$).

Now, we have the global reciprocity isomorphism
$$Gal(\overline{F}/F)^{ab}\xrightarrow{\simeq}H(\mathbb{Q}\backslash H(\mathbb{A}_f),$$
which equips $H(\mathbb{Q})\backslash H(\mathbb{A}_f)$ with the structure of a pro-finite $Gal(\overline{F}/F)$-set. The main theorem of CM for elliptic curves says that, if we identify the right hand side of $\eta$ with the set of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-points of the modular curve, then $\eta$ is in fact Galois-equivariant.

There is a slight sign issue here, since there are two possible choices for the reciprocity map (arithmetic or geometric Frobenius), but this is the general shape.